# In Microsoft BingAds what will be here $developerToken<developertokengoeshere>

Tags: php, bing, bing-ads-api

In Bing ads i know all my credentials like developer_token_id, account_id etc.

but how do i set in my php file like

```
$AuthenticationToken = $_SESSION['access_token'];
```

This 3 variables are not in session.

```
$DeveloperToken = "<dynamic value>";
$CustomerId = <dynamic value>;
$AccountId = <dynamic value>;
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on your dependencies or environment constraints. For example you could store the properties in session similar to access_token, or set in a config file. The [Server Side OAuth Authentication in PHP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn632721.aspx) sample sets the DeveloperToken inside ClientCredentials.php. I hope this helps!